# How does Cache Then Network strategy actually works?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Refering:

[Cache Then Network Strategy](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker)

There is a example with js code and service worker code.

My code:

```
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(DYNAMIC_CACHE).then(function(cache) {
        return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
        })
        // Network fallback
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Error when fething from network:', err)
          return caches.match(event.request);
        })
      })
  )
```

How does service-worker's code corresponds to `updatePage()` funciton?

I used that code, and put some `sleep(..)` on backend end, but even though I had cached request it was waiting to the response getting me result from backend request.

First I run request normally to cache it, and then I've changed backend to go to sleep and still request was waiting for response.

Comment: That code corresponds to a "network, falling back to cache" strategy, where the response will always block on the network and only fall back to the cache if the `fetch()` rejects. I think you copied the wrong code?

Comment: Naaah. Seems like it's good, go to https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker and find "Cache then Network" you'll see that this part. It's not like cache.match and then fetch, it's .open

Comment: The `fetch()` comes before the `caches.match()` (which only happens if `fetch()` rejects) in your promise chain. The code you posted is network first.

Comment: there is no `caches.match()` in this example, that's why its cache then network but still I can get it how it should work behind the scenes

Comment: Inside your `catch()` function, you've got a call to `return caches.match(event.request);` That part is executed as a fallback if the `fetch()` fails. So your code is using a "network, falling back to cache" strategy.

Comment: Hmmm that could be it... I wanted to have: Cache then Network and if both fails just use fallback to cache with single code

Comment: My advice is to read through https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/ and pick a strategy and reuse the code that makes sense for your use case.